# Template argument of type that is defined by inner typedef from other template class

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    bool f( int a ) { std::cout << "int" << std::endl; return true;};
    bool f( int a, int b ) { std::cout << "two int" << std::endl; return true;};
    bool f( float a ) {std::cout << "float" << std::endl; return true;};
    bool f( float a, float b ) {std::cout << "two float" << std::endl; return true;};
};

template <typename T>
struct Type
{
    typedef bool (A::*One)(T);
    typedef bool (A::*Two)(T, T);
};

template <typename T, typename Type<T>::One F >
void run(A & a)
{
    T tmp = 0;
    (a.*F)(tmp);
}


int main(int argc, char ** argv )
{
    A a;
    run<int, &A::f>(a);
    run<float, &A::f>(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Problem lies with syntax of `typename Type<T>::One F`. If I specify the actual method pointer instead of using my typedef from `Type` it works fine (see [here](http://ideone.com/xIMOu) and [here](http://ideone.com/cCzxV)).
Is there a way to use those typedefs from `Type` as template arguments?

Comment: Your example looks OK to me. What error are you getting, what compiler are you using?

Comment: +1 for posting a complete compilable example and a clear question. Your code compiled and worked for me.

Comment: [here](http://ideone.com/SBJpR) from Ideone, when compiled with IBM compiler I get `A non-type template parameter cannot have type "bool (float, float)".` and something similar from Sun CC compiler.

Comment: I think you haven't posted the code that you are using `bool (float, float)` has nothing to do with `Type<T>::One`. (Note, I don't generally bother to follow external links from SO.)

Comment: @CharlesBailey do you imagine what would happen without an example? I had a lot of trouble writing title... and I still think it might be wrong... And what compiler did you use?

Comment: I was just using an old gcc 4.4.4. Worked fine for me.

Comment: On Ideone it doesn't compile. When I tried compiling on the same machines using g++ provided there it appears to be compiling (though I can't run, because g++ libs are messed).
Still I am not able to compile this using neither IBM nor Sun compilers.

Comment: @elmo, there is probably a bug in Sun CC. Earlier versions give compile error, later one output "int\nint". Looking at the code, I see no reason excepted bug/unsupported feature for not displaying "int\nfloat" which is what I get with g++.

Comment: @elmo, on Ideone, you aren't using the same code.  There is a missing argument name F and you are passing twice tmp.

Comment: @AProgrammer indeed. My bad. [Corrected version](http://ideone.com/gx70s) compiles. So apparently there is something wrong with Sun and IBM compilers.

Comment: Pointers-to-member-function aren't integral types, are they? Surely they weren't allowed as template parameters in C++98/03?

Comment: @KerrekSB, even in C++98, non type parameters can be pointer to member (function or not). See 14.1/4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My current guess is that both IBM xlC and Sun CC have bugs.

The versions which give errors are probably confused by the use of `typename` in a template argument context but used to indicates that a dependant name is a type instead of introducing a type argument. Note that these compilers aren't conforming and don't demand `typename` to indicates that a dependant name is a type even in other contexts where it is needed (even for Sun CC versions where your code compile).